# Reading JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How to deserialize the following JSON using JSON.NET:

```
{
"adjusted_amount":200.0,
"amount":2,
"uid":"admin",
"extra_params": {"uid":"admin","ip":"83.26.141.183","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
}
```

I have the following code (but the problem is probably with 'extra_params' - it is not a string). I thought about creating new class for 'extra_params' but the problem is that the data in 'extra_params' may change.

I DONT NEED TO READ EXTRA_PARAMS AT ALL. All info I need, I get from the first 3 JSON variables.

My code:

```
public class RecData1
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int adjusted_amount { get; set; }
    public string extra_params { get; set; }
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecData1>(payload);
```

where payload = string pasted in the first quotation

EDIT: The error I get now:

```
Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'extra_params', line 1,     position 28.

at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsStringInternal()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Now: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'extra_params', line 1, position 28.

   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsStringInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is right? It could be an array of objects/strings rather than another JSON string. It cannot be the underscore, that is completely valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue you have is that adjusted_amount is not an int, but a decimal (also problem with localization can occur there).

Secondly, you could in your class RecData1 remove string extra_params and that will fix it.

```
{
"adjusted_amount":200,
"amount":2,
"uid":"admin",
"extra_params": {"uid":"admin","ip":"83.26.141.183","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
}

public class RecData1
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int adjusted_amount { get; set; }
    //public string extra_params { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I just figured that out and I was on the point of sending my own answer. But you were first! (The problem with the INT)

Answer (score 1):

You can have one more step forward by using `dynamic`:

```
 dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(payload);
 var data = new RecData1()
                 {
                     uid = x.uid,
                     amount = x.amount,
                     adjusted_amount = x.adjusted_amount
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because you extra param is not a string in your json.

It should be something like:

```
"extra_params": {"string........................................."}
```

It should work. Or you need to change your class to consider another object with all the properties you have in the json.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get `extra_params`, you can try this:

```
public class RecData1
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public int adjusted_amount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,string> extra_params { get; set; }
}

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecData1>(payload);
```